# Edit rejected as too minor - on my own post?

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

Firstly, **yes I was logged in**, this is completely reproducible, and it's nothing to do with not being logged in.

If you edit your own post, and while you're making the edit another user *suggests* the same edit, your edit will fail, with a confusing message.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Start editing your own answer.
2. Open a separate private-browsing tab.
3. Suggest an edit on the same post.
4. Go back to the first tab (logged-in user) and make exactly the same edit.
5. Attempt to save the change.

Save will fail, with this message:

[image]

This message is misleading, and seems to only happen if there is a pending suggested edit. It's as if it's being treated as an "accept & improve" action, particularly because **the message is identical to what you get if you select "improve" on a suggested edit** and don't actually change anything.

If a normal/approved edit has been made instead, a much more useful banner message is shown:

[image]

Comment: Also, if the suggested edit was accepted *after you opened the edit dialog*, then your edit would have been a null edit (the change was already there).

Comment: It wasn't accepted - when I cancelled my edit it was still listed as edit (1) and I subsequently accepted it

Comment: and when I say "still", I'm pretty sure it wasn't suggested *before* I started my edit

Comment: If the suggested edit was still outstanding, your edit would have auto-cancelled it (if it worked).

Comment: I'm not sure what was going on in this case then.

Comment: I think the sequence was (1) I started editing (2) OP suggested edit (3) I hit save. Is there any way for me to experiment with different sequences, or would I need to enlist a sub-2k user's help?

Comment: I didn't realize I can suggest edits when not logged in. I can use that to attempt to reproduce it

Comment: You can suggest edits as an anonymous user, yes.

Comment: Ok, confirmed, and the sequence is as I thought. The message is `You made too few changes to the post to improve it.` I'll edit this question accordingly.

Comment: question updated

Comment: I can't believe people are still upvoting the "were you logged in comment?" - I mean I said it **in bold** :-)

Comment: I deleted it for you.

Comment: thanks. I've moved the note to the top of the post so hopefully no-one else will suspect it as the issue. Seems like a straightforward enough bug at the end of the day. Normally you don't have the option of editing while there's a pending suggestion, so probably doesn't happen very often.

Answer (score -21):

When you start editing a post, and another edit is made to the post after you started, your edit needs to be "more substantial" than the other edit for it to be applied; if it isn't, you edit doesn't override the other edit.  In this case, your edit, being identical, was clearly not "more substantial" than the edit made by the other user, and so your edit did not override theirs.

This has nothing to do with the edit being treated as an "edit and improve" nor does it a bug at all.  There was an edit conflict, and the other user submitted their edit first, so they won.

Comment: While it may not be a bug, it's certainly a confusing message to receive, and not very user friendly.  There isn't a way to see that others tried to make the same edit, so the fact that the post is already changed is not really in the realm of expected results for most people.

Comment: @Claies I would go even further than that - the message is *incorrect* - it doesn't say "your edit is too close to a suggested edit", it says "You made too few changes to the post", which is *not true*. So even if if it's just a case that the error message is wrong, it's still a bug.

Comment: @CupawnTae But it *is* true.  The problem is that he made too few changes, not that it was too similar to another edit.

Comment: He made too few changes to the post as it exists currently on the server, not too few changes to the post that exists on his client;  This is a matter of what the software sees vs. what the user sees.  again, while it's not a bug, it's not something that someone other than a programmer might expect.  (which is ironic, since it's on a programming QA website)

Comment: @Claies He made too few changes to be able to submit the edit.  Trying to have error message that try to make distinctions between server/client versions, instead of just saying that the edit that wasn't sufficient substantial made too few changes would be, in my eyes, writing an error message for an audience of programmers.  All someone seeing this error message needs to know is that their edit didn't change enough, and if they want to apply it, it needs to be more substantial.

Comment: @Claies it's not even the state on the server, because the second user's edit hasn't been approved. To *every* client other than the second user's, the original post still stands. There is no mention of another edit or **suggested edit** in the error message

Comment: @Servy it was my own post. I added 8 vital characters. I should *always* be allowed to do that

Comment: @CupawnTae And you *can* do that, by approving or rejecting the pending edit and then applying your change, or if the other edit is no longer pending, re-editing the post after getting the latest version.  So you're *not* prevented from making the change, you're simply prevented from *unknowingly* reverting another user's change.  You either need to *intentionally* revert the other user's change, or apply your change after theirs.

Comment: @Servy but the point is I didn't know about the other user's edit, and the system didn't warn me about it. I agree it shouldn't allow me to inadvertently kill someone's suggested edit, but it should at least say *this would conflict with a previous edit*. Also, if I did make a *more substantial* change, are you saying that would then silently nuke the other edit? Sounds like *another* bug to me if so.

Comment: @CupawnTae if you feel that the error is lacking sufficient information, then feel free to propose a wording change to the error message.  In the case of conflicting edits, the most substantial edit is kept, and the less substantial edit is lost.  This is by design, not a bug.  If you want to propose a change to that behavior, you're more than welcome to.

Comment: @Servy could such a message be applied _only when another edit has been made/suggested_, or would it be shown every time a null edit was attempted as well? Or could the system detect identical deltas and have a different message saying "it's ok, someone else fixed that for you?" Without knowing this, it's hard for me to propose something. However, that doesn't invalidate my original point or make it not a bug when a user message does not reflect the reality of what the issue is.

Comment: @CupawnTae I would certainly imagine that it's possible, but I'm not a developer.  Again, the error message is *completely* accurate.  You may feel that it could use some additional information; if you want to propose a change based on that, you're free to do so.

Comment: I continue to contend that the error message is indeed accurate from the state of the data the server sees, and the problem is that the user is trying to edit stale data without realizing that it's stale data.  Sometimes *completely accurate* error messages can be *completely confusing* from the user's perspective.

Comment: @Claies Which is why I said that if you or Cup feel that the error message isn't clear, you can propose a change to the text of the error message.

Comment: Also, @Servy I actually think this answer is not correct. If an edit has been approved, there's a different message, and it's actually a useful one: `This post has been edited 1 time since you began. Your edit can only be saved if it is more thorough than the currently saved edit.` - I'll edit a screenshot into the question